# MRTK Grid Object Collection UpdateCollection() not working if called from script

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am using the `GridObjectCollection` Script from MRTK to display a number of buttons. I am instantiating the buttons dynamically through a script and place them as children of the `GridObjectCollection` GameObject. Now you can Update the collection through the `UpdateCollection()` function. Everything works as expected except the following case:

If i want to display a set of different buttons in the same `GridObjectCollection`, i destroy all children of the collection and instantiate the new buttons as before and call the `UpdateCollection()` function. But the collection is not updating properly. The old buttons were destroyed and the new added, but the placement is shifted. If i click the UpdateCollection button in inspector, the collection is correctly updated.

Why `UpdateCollection()` is not working as expected after modifying the content of the collection?

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed the problem. If the collection is updated in the next frame, the update works as expected.
So i am starting a Coroutine and call the update function there.

```
private IEnumerator InvokeUpdateCollection()
{
    yield return null;
    gridObjectCollection.UpdateCollection();
}
```