# MRTK - Scrolling object collection - How can the UpdateCollection()-Method be used in the script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I would like to call the UpdateCollection () method in the script in order to generate a certain number of buttons that I previously created dynamically.

Can someone tell me how I can use the UpdateCollection () method in the script? You can easily execute the method via the Inspector, now you want to use the method in the script.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to either create a public variable `public ScrollingObjectCollection scrollingCollection;` in your script and assign the component in the Unity-Editor or use `GameObject.Find("MyGameObjectName").GetComponent<ScrollingObjectCollection>()` to assign the variable in the Start() method.

After instantiating your buttons you can call the `scrollingCollection.UpdateContent()` method.

However, if you are using a GridObjectCollection inside your ScrollingObjectCollection in order to layout the children you have to create a variable of that type aswell, assign the GridObjectCollection script and call `objectCollection.UpdateCollection()` before calling `scrollingCollection.UpdateContent()`.

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65561456/14029370) states, this should be done inside a coroutine on order to work as expected.

Here's an excerpt from my code:

```
public GridObjectCollection objectCollection;
public ScrollingObjectCollection scrollingCollection;

private void Start()
{
    InsertIntoObjectCollection(20);
}

public void InsertIntoObjectCollection(int count)
{
    StartCoroutine(InsertIntoObjectCollection_Coroutine(count));
}

public IEnumerator InsertIntoObjectCollection_Coroutine(int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var newErrorMessage = Instantiate(singleErrorMessagePrefab, objectCollection.transform);
    }
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    objectCollection.UpdateCollection();
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    scrollingCollection.UpdateContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the method `UpdateContent` from `ScrollingObjectCollection` class has the same purpose as `UpdateCollection` from the Editor.

Here's the description about this function:

> Sets up the scroll clipping object and the interactable components
> according to the scroll content and chosen settings.

Doc link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.ui.scrollingobjectcollection.updatecontent?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.7.0#Microsoft_MixedReality_Toolkit_UI_ScrollingObjectCollection_UpdateContent